# Jquery: How to add TD into TR of TFoot

Tags: jquery, html

below is a sample tfoot. here i want to add some more td into TR of TFoot.
how to achieve it with jquery. thanks

```
<tfoot>
        <tr class="webgrid-footer">
            <td colspan="6">1 
            <a href="http://localhost:13562/WebGrid_Sample2/Show2?page=2&amp;sort=ID&amp;sortdir=ASC" data-swhglnk="true">2</a> 
            <a href="http://localhost:13562/WebGrid_Sample2/Show2?page=3&amp;sort=ID&amp;sortdir=ASC" data-swhglnk="true">3</a> 
            <a href="http://localhost:13562/WebGrid_Sample2/Show2?page=4&amp;sort=ID&amp;sortdir=ASC" data-swhglnk="true">4</a> 
            <a href="http://localhost:13562/WebGrid_Sample2/Show2?page=2&amp;sort=ID&amp;sortdir=ASC" data-swhglnk="true"><img src="/images/next.png"></a> 
            <a href="http://localhost:13562/WebGrid_Sample2/Show2?page=4&amp;sort=ID&amp;sortdir=ASC" data-swhglnk="true"><img src="/images/last.png"></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
</tfoot>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 
[Append function](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

You can do something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

     var myTr = $(".webgrid-footer");
     myTr.append("<td colspan='6'>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</td>");
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.webgrid-footer').html('<td>...</td><td>....</td>');
```